# How to list all users in Razor View?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, view, identity

I am making a page where the users will be approved by the Admin. The problem
is when i try to list all users i get only one of them.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYE91.png

This is my Approve.cshtml.cs

```
 public class ApproveModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
  
    public ApproveModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
     

    }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
  
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        foreach (var user in _db.UserRoles)
        {
            UserId = user.UserId;
            if (user.RoleId == "2")
            {
                IsSelected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                IsSelected = false;
            }
           
        }
        return Page();
    }

}
```

And this is my Approve.cshtml

```
<form method="post">
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h2>Approve users</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-check m-1">
            <input asp-for="@Model.IsSelected" class="form-check-input" />
            <label class="form-check-label">
                @Model.User.Identity.Name
            </label>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:auto" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use foreach in the view but it didn't work or i made it wrong...

Thank you in advance for the help i really need it <3

Comment: You should use `foreach` loop. Retrieve users list as a model in the view `@model List<User>` then use this `@foreach(var user in @Model)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could consider created a list of user to store the all the admin approved user.

Then in the page using foreach to loop all the user and show it in the client view.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

ApproveUsers mode:

```
public class ApproveUsers
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Page model:

```
public class Error2Model : PageModel
{
    public List<ApproveUsers> Users { get; set; } = new List<ApproveUsers>();

    public void OnGet()
    {

        foreach (var user in _db.UserRoles)
        {
            ApproveUsers ap = new ApproveUsers();
            ap.UserId = user.UserId;
            if (user.RoleId == "2")
            {
                ap.IsSelected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ap.IsSelected = false;
            }
            Users.Add(ap);

        }

    }
}
```

Page view:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h2>Approve users</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            @foreach (var item in Model.Users)
            {
                <div class="form-check m-1">
                    <input asp-for="@item.IsSelected" class="form-check-input" />
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        @item.UserId
                    </label>
                </div>
            }


        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:auto" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```